# Concat gives flickering result

Tags: ffmpeg

I really don't get this; I use ffmpeg concat one 2 files and the audio is concated well, but the videos aren't. The second video causes freeze/flicker/green screen instead.

`'ffmpeg -y -f concat -i concat.txt -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mkv`

Comparing the files, I have made them as identical as possible:

- **input.mkv1**
  `Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1280x720 60fps [V: h264 main L4.1, yuv420p, 1280x720 [default]]
  Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo [A: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo [default]]`
- **input2.mkv**
  `Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1280x720 60fps [V: English [eng] (h264 main L4.1, yuv420p, 1280x720) [default]]
  Audio: AAC 48000Hz stereo [A: English [eng] (aac, 48000 Hz, stereo) [default]]`

What could cause this behavior?

[image: Flicker]

Comment: How did you generate the 2nd file (command)?

Comment: 1st file was generated through OBS as .flv and made into .mkv. 2nd file was generated through Premiere Pro and made into .mkv. If I define 2nd file first, the 1st file's video gets messed up

Comment: Any console warnings/errors during encoding/playback?

Comment: I ended up switching method. There were warnings which I missed because I was also looking for errors, but I didn't manage to troubleshoot the warnings either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this solution instead: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Converting into .ts allowed me to concat without weird flickering.